# Flask Message Flashing

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently learning Flask and trying to use message flashing in one of my project. As I couldn't get it to display the message properly, I decided to go a step back and checked out some introductory tutorials.

I followed the one on Tutorialspoint ([link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_message_flashing.htm)) and noticed that it wasn't working on my machine. The message 'You were successfully logged in' wasn't visible. 
Later, I tried the official Tutorial ([link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/#message-flashing-pattern)), which is working as expected.

Both tutorials seem to be using mostly the same examples and codes. The main difference seems to by lying in the Html templates. The official tutorial uses an additional layout.html, which is being extended by the other templates.

Now I have a working example, but no understanding WHY it is working.
Does anyone here maybe know the reason why only one of these tutorials is working? Or is it the fault of my local environment? I'm using Python 3.7.1 together with Flask 1.0.2

Greatly appreciate any help, thanks in advance !

EDIT:
I inspected the html output from the first tutorial and now noticed that it actually got updated with the flashed message but got "scrambled".

```
<head>
  <title>Flask Message flashing</title>
</head>
<body>


        <ul>

           <li<you were="" successfully="" logged="" in<="" li="">

        </li<you></ul>



  <h1>Flask Message Flashing Example</h1>
  <p>Do you want to <a href="/login">
     <b>log in?</b></a></p>
```

This is due to a typo in the tutorial's code:
     `<li<{{ message }}</li>`
So this answers my question

Comment: I'd include the code you actually created that isn't working-- hard to diagnose otherwise. By extending the template-- essentially the `{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %} ...` code is going to get executed on every page of your site (shouldn't make a difference though, flashed messages stack up and wait until they're looked for)

Comment: I cannot see why the code on your first url wouldn't work. I suspect there is an error in your code.

Comment: I just copy&pasted the code as it was presented in the tutorial, saved the two html files in a "templates" folder and ran the Flash.py .... I noticed something interesting about the output & I will update my question